# Creating a PDF File

Tags: pdf

I have a folder that contains subfolders with different files inside them (html, css, images, audio files ...).
It's basically the contents of a book.
How can I create a PDF file from this folder, is it possible?

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: If you can display the HTML with images in a browser, *Print it as PDF*. That would not incorporate anything other than a single page, nor would it bring in audio.